# HTML script constantly sync for every user

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code. It is a green image (by default) and when anybody click to this image it starts blinking then for the second click it change to a red picture. Is it possible to sync it for every user who's on the website (live). So everyone see the same at the same time and if someone clicks on it, flash for everyone?

```
<img id="red" src="green.gif" />
<script>
    var tId4, images4 = [],
    isBlinking4 = false;
    currImg4 = 0,

    images4[0] = new Image(); images4[0].src = "green.gif";
    images4[1] = new Image(); images4[1].src = "red.gif";
    images4[2] = new Image(); images4[2].src = "blinking3.gif";

        var img4 = document.getElementById("red");

        img4.onclick = function () {
            if (isBlinking4) {
                clearInterval(tId4);
                isBlinking4 = false;
                currImg4 = currImg4 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                img4.src = images4[currImg4].src;

            } else {
                isBlinking4 = true;
                tId4 = setInterval(function () {
                    var src4 = document.getElementById("red").src;
                    // blink
                    document.getElementById("red").src = src4 == images4[currImg4].src ? images4[2].src : images4[currImg4].src;
                }, 700);
            }

        }
</script>
```

Comment: You need a backend first.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set up a back-end server, so that people viewing the HTML/Javascript front-end can send updates to it and receive notifications when something has changed, as per the [client-server model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model).

Personally, I'd implement this using [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), perhaps via the [ActionCable](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) feature of Ruby on Rails.